# WCF how to properly pass arbitrary data store query?

Tags: c#, .net, database, wcf

I have a WCF service written against some DB, and I need to filter and return data based on complex queries. What is the best way to do it?

- I know that it is a bad practice, and i should provide separate service methods like GetOrdersByProductId(object Id), but my queries are really huge, about 15 predicates = 225 functions  - no sense.
- RIA services is not an option here.
- I can serialize expression Tree, with MetaLinq but i think executing arbitrary Lambda against server is even more dangerous than pure SQL query, you can put any function call there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't matter how complex your queries are. What matters is how they will be used.

If  your callers need to pass 15 parameters in order to fill the 15 predicates in your query, then they have to pass them - as simple as that. Create a "QueryParameters" class instead of using 15 separate parameters, but the information needs to be supplied.

Do not allow the callers of your service to arbitrarily invent new queries. You should decide which queries will be available, and how the parameters will be specified. Then simply expose those parameters to the callers of your service.